# How do I download all the files in a directory with cURL?

Tags: windows, bash, shell, curl

I am using cURL to try to download all files in a certain directory.

Here's what my list of files looks like:

[image: List of Files]

I have tried to do in bash script: `iiumlabs.[].csv.pgp` and `iiumlabs*` and I guess cURL is not big on wildcards.

```
curl -u login:pass ftp.myftpsite.com/iiumlabs* -O
```

**Question:** How do I download this directory of files using cURL?

Comment: Why not use `wget` with `-r` and maybe some other options instead?  `curl` can be made to do it with some scripting around it, but there are other tools that are better suited.

Comment: Why not use good old `ftp` with a script file to `mget` all the files?

Comment: @ChrisS thank you, can i do sFTP with mget?

Comment: @cjc thank you! how would i do sftp with wget?

Comment: Is the server SFTP only, or can you login with SSH?  If the server isn't limited to SFTP only, you would probably be better off using scp/rsync.

Comment: im sorry i dont know the difference. in filezilla to connect to it i connect to sftp.thesite.com

Comment: @Zoredache does what i said make any sense?

Comment: @Zoredache let me know if i can clarify something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curl does not support recursive download. Use `wget --mirror --no-parent [URL]`

**EDIT:** For SSH, from the man page of curl:

Get a file from an SSH server using SFTP:

```
    curl -u username sftp://shell.example.com/etc/issue
```

Get a file from an SSH server using SCP using a private key to authenticate:

```
    curl -u username: --key ~/.ssh/id_dsa --pubkey ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub \
            scp://shell.example.com/~/personal.txt
```

Comment: great! what would be the syntax for sftp (transfer over ssh) ?

Comment: thank yuou very much!!!!!! what is SCP? scp://..... if the key is stored on my machine can i just point to c:/.....

Comment: scp is an old way to use ssh to transfer files. The latest version of ssh support SFTP. I do not know the syntax for local files in curl. You can enable some debugging options in curl. Besides curl you can use `pscp` and `psftp` to transfer files. See: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html.